# Percentage width less pixels with least number of DOM elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find the pure CSS solution that will render this layout using the least number of DOM elements and without any images.

[image: Desired layout]

The real problem is getting a div to be 50% width minus some pixels - e.g. 50% wide less 10px

I've set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhxWp/1/) with my best effort - this works perfectly, but I'm hoping for something that has less DOM elements.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="backHalf">
    <div class="backLeft1"></div>
    <div class="backLeft2"></div>
    <div class="backLeft3"></div>
</div>
<div class="backHalf">
    <div class="backRight1"></div>
    <div class="backRight2"></div>
    <div class="backRight3"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.main, .backHalf div { height: 10px; background-color: #000}
.backHalf { width: 50%; float:left}
.backMain { height: 50px; }
.backLeft1 { margin-right: 10px; }
.backRight1 { margin-left: 10px; }
.backLeft2 { margin-right: 20px; }
.backRight2 { margin-left: 20px; }
.backLeft3 { margin-right: 30px; }
.backRight3 { margin-left: 30px; }
```

By the way, I'm sure if there is a better solution it won't have MANY less DOM elements but even losing one would help.  E.g. if it's possible to achieve the same result without the 'backHalf' divs that would help a lot.

Comment: less dom elements? don't be greedy now, you are doing just fine

Comment: box-sizing is your friend if you don't need older browsers

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this without a CSS preprocessor, but I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS3's new function `calc()`, which allows you to calculate widths or heights directly in CSS.

Example : `calc(50% - 10px)`;

Here is where I am so far : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HnR2/), it's pretty much done, but I have some `clear` issues. Any ideas?

[See this reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: This is great. Should have mentioned that I'm ideally looking to support IE8 - I know I'm asking a lot here!!!  However, I may use Mustache to present a slightly different template for IE8 so that newer browsers don't suffer.

Comment: By the way, your clear issues go away if you re-order the floated divs, so they're staggered left/right/left/right/left/right